# LibreOffice Calc autofilter shows weird display

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, autofilter

The `autofilter` in `LibreOffice Calc` does not behave as expected. To be precise, the autofilter sometimes does not show items as checked when they should be.

**MWE:**

I have one simple column and apply autofilter:

[image]

Next, I open the filter options by clicking on the small triangle. The `4` is unchecked, the same is true for the `All` button (but both are expected to be checked):

[image]

Now, I click on `All`. What is up with the `2` not being allowed to be clicked?

[image]

I click `All` again. The `4` is still unchecked:

[image]

I scroll down...

[image]

and up again. Now the `4` is checked. Hurray!

[image]

**Analysis:**

The main issue is that I would like to know for sure which items are checked (thus to be found when filtering) and which are not. Just think of a large document with thousands of rows where you can not verify which items are included by hand / eye.

Because scrolling down and up again fixed the issue, I assume this as a GUI problem.

**Version:**

Version: 5.1.6.2
Build ID: 1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial2
CPU Threads: 4; OS Version: Linux 4.4; UI Render: default; 
Locale: en-US (en_US.UTF-8); Calc: group

Comment: I tried to reproduce this issue using 5.1.6.2 on Linux Mint xenial, but could not -- everything worked correctly.

Comment: Thanks for trying to verify the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to LibreOffice version 6 solved the problem.